# How to unmerge a package and it's dependencies in Gentoo?

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'd like to remove a package from my Gentoo system. The `--unmerge` option will remove the package without any consideration, and `--depclean` will remove the package only if there is no package installed on the system which depends on the to-be-removed package.

How can I make it remove the package and all reverse depended packages?

Answer (score 1):

First find out what the reverse dependencies are and then remove them.

Finding out what they are can be done using`equery` from `gentoolkit`. Starting it in the `depends` (`d`) mode will find the direct dependencies and the `--indirect` (`-D`) flag will recursively look at their reverse dependencies.

You can get a copy/pasteable list of all these packages (source package not be printed there) using:

```
equery d -D octave | sed 's/^ *\([^ ]*\)-[0-9].*/\1/' | sort -u |  tr '\n' ' '
```

Note that his will only look at installed packages. If you have have already removed packages, you may have to rebuild missing dependencies (using some variation of `emerge @world`) before `equery` finds the reverse dependencies "behind" them.